# How to define Textchanged event for edit text?

Tags: android

how to define textchanged event for EditText??

Thanks,
Balu.

Comment: Have you tried searching google or SO? There are thousands of tutorials

Comment: To be fair, the tutorials aren't really user-friendly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need this:

```
inputView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: Does this go in the fragment or activity?

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi anywhere where you have reference to the EditText instance.